# How to call Action on Button click from JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

With ASP.NET MVC, I want to call action of controller on Button Click from JQuery.

**Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult PersonInfo(string name, string city)
        {
            // other code for assign ViewData
            return View();
        } 
    }
```

I have two textBox and one Button in Index.chtml page. I want to display Url like 'http://localhost:2526/PersonName'. for city I want optional perameter and don't want in Url. so, I mapped route as below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "",
                 new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
            );

routes.MapRoute(
          "PersonInfo", // Route name
          "{name}", // URL with parameters
          new { controller = "Home", action = "PersonInfo", name= ""  , city = ""} // Parameter defaults
```

From browser if I enter Url like 'http://localhot:2526/John' then PersonInfo view displayed successfully.

I visited [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753779/mvc-button-click-to-action) related my question. But I also want to pass parameters.

Anyone help me How can I call action on button click from JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass parameters as query string for example:

```
$('#buttonId').click(function(){
     document.location = 
    '@Url.Action("MyAction","MyController")'+'?'+'parameterToSend = @value';
});
```

your link will be like

```
MyController/MyAction?parameterToSend=value
```

Comment: I tried with your solution but in my case it giving me 'localhost:2526/?name=John' in browser and page not redirect to personInfo view. please see my route map (second one). I want to pass Two parameter and for url only want one parameter to display in route path.

Comment: its not appropriate to use mapping for showing just one parameters, its better to post your parameter using the form and showing the parameter that you want in query string, in another word you can post your form to MyController/MyAction?parameterToSend=value

Comment: can you provide me example for my case? what changes should i need in route map and in JQuery call to action?

Answer (score 0):

You want to add the paramaters inside the Url.Action Method to avoid the / at the end of your host.

@Url.Action("PersonInfo","Home" , new {name=Model.Name, city=Model.City })
//I believe this will look at your routes and generate localhost:2526/John/JohnsCity

Are your paramaters part of your model? If so the above will work.  If not than you can use 1AmirJalali answer but replace the / before appending the paramaters since if they paramaters are not part of your model then they are probably coming via javascript variables.

Comment: I want URL path like localhost:2526/John only. I want to pass City as extra parameter. Don't want to use city in URL. See Routes.MapRoute in my Question for PersonInfo action. If I am passing only name parameter then it's working perfectly. but I am passing city parameter with name parameter then Url.Action returning blank string. so, current page(Index.chtml) is no redirected to PersonInfo.chtml.

Comment: Change your route to {name}/{city} and change city = "" to city = UrlParameter.Optional  also when adding new route with an actual controller or action besure to put these before the variable routes so they will be called.

Comment: Yes I can achieve by changing route as mentioned you but is there anyway without changing my route (because I don't want city in URL)?. I don't want allow path like localhost:2526/John/JohnsCity. only want to allow localhost:2526/John. if user doesn't enter city name then all John persons will be displayed. if user enter city name then localhost:2526/John will display John personInfo which has city equals to value entered in city textBox.

Comment: I just want to pass City as extra Parameter for filtering purpose.

Comment: If you want to use the city as a filter the only way to I can think of to not display the city in the address bar would be to redirect to /name/city then in your action set city as a session variable then redirect to /name and use your session value to filter.  Is there a reason you don't want to show the city in the url?

Comment: Yes. Lets say If I entered url directly without opening Index.chtml like localhost:2526/John then user can see all record of John. I don;t want to display filter parameter other than name in URL. In future it's posible that other parameter added for Filter So, I just want name in URL.

Comment: If I am using session for city then It's possible that if I enter URL  in new tab localhost:2526/John in browser then also  city filter will apply if user already applied filter (Index.chtml) city value in other tab.But I want localhost:2526/John URL return all John name person if user enter url directly in browser.

Comment: The I would go with a basic form.  You can change the action of the form via javascript to whatever the user enters in the name field and after they click submit you can get the other filters via Request.Form["inputname"].

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21600/discussion-between-michael-grassman-and-jignesh-thakker)